# How can I add 's' by foreach loop through the different list model object?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am working on MVC 5 project. There is list of items for bind the drop down.

View,

```html
  <select id="category" class="select-option">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.listServiceType)
                            {
                                <option value="@item">@item</option>
                            }
                            <option value="Product">Products</option>
                        </select>
```

It's output is,

```html
<select id="category" class="select-option">
                            <option>Select</option>
                                <option value="Consultant">Consultant</option>
                                <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
                            <option value="Product">Products</option>
                        </select>
```

And actually I want this output,

```html
<select id="category" class="select-option">
                            <option>Select</option>
                                <option value="Consultant">Consultants</option>
                                <option value="Contractor">Contractors</option>
                            <option value="Product">Products</option>
                        </select>
```

How can I add 's' word to the `foreach` items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Html.Raw here, like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listServiceType)
{
  <option value="@item">@Html.Raw(item)s</option>
}
```